# save for loop result as a string in text file

Tags: php, for-loop

this is my try:-

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
{
    echo $i.',';

}
 // save the new xml file
file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $i);
echo ' Creat Text File';
?>
```

This works but it only saves the last loop value. I want to save all the loop's output.

Comment: Obviously it will print last value in the file as the command which writes into the file is out of the loop. So first, the whole loop will get executed and the last value will be the input for `file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $i);`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
$px = '';
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
{
    $px.=$i.',';

}

// save the new xml file
file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $px);
echo ' Creat Text File';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$i` iterator variable is incremented at every loop iteration. It does not aggregate its previous values, so naturally at the end of the loop `$i` evaluates to the last value assigned to it, `99999` in this case.

To achieve what you seem to look for, just aggregate the different values of `$i` in a separate variable, so at the end of the loop this variable will be a string made of all the values of `$i`.

For example:

```
$all_values = '';
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++) {
   $all_values .= $i.',';
}

file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $all_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
    {
        $output .= $i.',';
    }
    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $output);
    echo ' Creat Text File';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$str = "";   
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
{
    $str.= $i.',';

}
// save the new xml file
file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $str);
echo ' Creat Text File';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another variable like this because `i` every time change the value for every loop:

```
<?php
$k="";
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
{
    echo $k.=$i.',';

}
    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $k);
echo ' Creat Text File';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did an echo, this will not save the value anywhere.

Try this:

```
<?php
echo 'Start creating text file';
$result = '';
for($i=1;$i<100000;$i++)
{
    $result .= $i.',';
    echo 'Adding '.$i.', to result';
}
    // save the new xml file
    file_put_contents('tab_id.text', $result);
echo 'End creating text file';
?>
```